# Postgresql 10 add user to schema public

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to have a seperate database with a separate user and rw-access:

```
postgres=# \l
-[ RECORD 3 ]-----+----------------------------
Name              | report
Owner             | report
Encoding          | UTF8
Collate           | en_US.UTF-8
Ctype             | en_US.UTF-8
Access privileges | =T/report              +
                  | report=CTc/report

postgres=# \du
Role name  | report
Attributes |
Member of  | {}
```

Now comes the problem:

```
report=> \c report
You are now connected to database "report" as user "report".
report=>  CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
                 ^
```

So I tried looked at the schemas:

```
report=> \dn+
List of schemas
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------------------
Name              | public
Owner             | postgres
Access privileges | postgres=UC/postgres   +
Description       | standard public schema
```

And Im wondering, why the created role is not listed. I have some other databases and accounts, where this works fine. I just deleted them from the cut.
Here is the search path:

```
report=> show search_path;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------
search_path | "$user", public
```

I think the problem is, that the report-user is not part of the public schema. How can I add him?

**UPDATE 1**

I followed the advise and did

```
postgres=> GRANT CREATE, USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO report;
postgres=# \dn+
List of schemas
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------------------
Name              | public
Owner             | postgres
Access privileges | postgres=UC/postgres   +
                  | report=UC/postgres   
Description       | standard public schema
```

But when I login with report, I get the following result:

```
report=> \dn+
List of schemas
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------------------
Name              | public
Owner             | postgres
Access privileges | postgres=UC/postgres   +
Description       | standard public schema
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the output of the second advice:

```
postgres=# SELECT nspname, nspname::bytea
postgres-# FROM pg_namespace
postgres-# WHERE nspname LIKE '%public%';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------
nspname | public
nspname | \x7075626c6963
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
report=> set search_path to public;
SET
report=>  CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
          ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
          NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
          AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
          ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
          SALARY         REAL
          );
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
                 ^
report=>  CREATE TABLE public.COMPANY(
          ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
          NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
          AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
          ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
          SALARY         REAL
          );
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE public.COMPANY(
```

kind regards

Comment: This is weird.

I'd suspect an event trigger that removes the permission again, but then you'd *never* see the changed permissions.

One thing that sticks out is that you see the permission as superuser, but not as normal user. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes I can confirm. I found a "workaround". After GRANT dev to report I can create tables without specifying the schema. (dev is a working role).

Comment: There is something quite nonstandard about your PostgreSQL. Did anybody mess with the catalogs? Is this standard PostgreSQL? Because there is nothing in standard PostgreSQL that would cause such a behavior.

Comment: Im not sure. I think I will create a second machine so I can setup the permissions from scratch, test it and change the database backend to the new machine.